# Jquery selector for a empty div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How select a empty divs and divs with only one space character, ej:

Ej:
A jquery rule selector that select this:

```
<div class="thumbnails"></div>
<div class="thumbnails"> </div>
```

but that NOT select this:

```
<div class="thumbnails">Lorem ipsum amet</div>
```

---

I tried this

```
$('.thumbnails:empty').css('background-color', "#f0f");
```

and works fine with:

```
<div class="thumbnails"></div>
```

but does not select this case (note space character):

```
<div class="thumbnails"> </div>
```

Test: http://jsbin.com/ozohak/1/edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your own Jquery selector, and check trimmed text (see http://jsbin.com/ozohak/12/edit)

```
$.expr[':'].blank = function(obj){
  return obj.innerHTML.trim().length === 0;
};

$('.thumbnails:blank').addClass('selected');
```

**EDIT:** To avoid issues in IE8 and lower:

```
$.expr[':'].blank = function(obj){
  return !$.trim($(obj).text()).length;
};

$('.thumbnails:blank').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: .trim() will break in IE8 and lower.. you should use $.trim(string) instead

Comment: It works too ^^ You can also check innerText if you havn't html in your body

Comment: +1 `return obj.innerHTML.trim() === '';` and also: `return $.trim(obj.innerHTML) === '';` **But I like the most** `!$.trim(obj.innerHTML).length` ...just in IE8 we'll have troubles so use: `return !$.trim($(obj).text()).length;`

Comment: Is the $(obj) really necessary ? It seems not very optimized to call a jquery selector to make a such simple operation on a DOM node.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to detect elements with no text

```
$('.thumbnails').filter(function(i,v){
    return $.trim($(v).text()).length == 0;
}).css('background-color', "#f0f");
```

http://jsbin.com/ozohak/5/edit

EDIT:

You can select empty elements and one space using the filter function also if that is your requirement

```
$('.thumbnails').filter(function(i,v){
    return $(v).text() == '' || $(v).text() == ' ';
}).css('background-color', "#f0f");
```

http://jsbin.com/ozohak/10/edit

Comment: Incredible, 2 downvotes without a comment. S.O. should not accept downvotes without posting a comment. I'll suggest on META

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `filter()` with a regex to make sure `text()` is empty:

```
$('.thumbnails')
    .filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().replace(/\W/gi, '') == '';
    })
    .addClass('selected');
```

[**Updated example**](http://jsbin.com/ozohak/8/edit)

Note you could also compare to `html()` if you want to allow HTML elements within the divs.

Comment: And the reason for a downvote for a valid answer with a working example is...?

Comment: It was not me :( , btw your answers are OK!, but Julian Lafont better fit.

Comment: @karacas No problem, his answer was more elegant. No reason for a phantom downvote though :(

Answer (score -1):

There's no selector that would check for blank content, but here's something that might help:

```
$('div').each(function(i,e) {
  if ($(e).html().trim() == "")
    $(e).html("");
});

$('.thumbnails:empty').addClass('selected');
```

Regards.

Answer (score -2):

You can use following code

```
$('*').each(function() {
         if ($(this).text() == "") { // you can change this to whatever #ex: char length
                   //Do Something
         }
});
```